# crystal reports - datetime group header does not show time, only date. need to display date AND time

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report that has a group that references a DATETIME column generated by a SQL Server stored procedure.

When I right-click and Format the Group, the Format Editor displays a sample of the field's output, like so:

> Monday, March 01, 1999 1:23:45PM

However, when I preview the report, it only shows as such:

> Monday, March 01, 1999

I need it to display/sort by the time, as well. Once again, the DB column it points to is of type DATETIME.

I am running CR 11.5 and SQL Server 2008R2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what you see when you don't use any formatting at all ? Plus I know it sounds so simple but have you checked width of group ? May be text is getting cropped out ?

Comment: Are you grouping on this field or only displaying it?

Comment: @JackLock it isn't possible to not have any formatting on the Group; for a DATETIME data type, the Crystal default format is System Default Long Format. I played around with this and even set the format to display time only (just to see if it would display), but it still only displayed the date. Width is not an issue; I set the width far beyond what is needed to display the datetime value.

Comment: @Ryan i am grouping on it.

Comment: @user1330266: Are there actual times in the data or just zeros?  if you run the query by itself what do you get?

Comment: @Limey there are actual times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to rethink grouping on a datetime field if you want it distinct down to the second; the chance that multiple records share the exact same datetime field are usually extremely low, negating the usefulness of grouping.

For this reason, CR may have taken the liberty of assuming you only wanted to group by the date instead of the full datetime value. You can check by performing the following steps: Select "Report" from the CR toolbar → "Group Expert" → Select your group on the right and hit "Options" → At the bottom of the "Common" tab there will be a dropdown labeled "The section will be printed". Verify that it says "For each second" instead of "For each day" or some other value.

It's from here that you can control how small or large of a net you want CR to group for your datetime values.